# alphabetic or numeric or alphanumeric

Tags: pattern, wordplay, number-sequence

Find the possible next three positive numbers in the below sequence:

5, 8, 10, 9, 8, 3, 18, __, __, __

And based on the above, as a bonus, find those 4 **smallest positive** numbers that *cannot* be fit into the above sequence !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a sequence where

> The last letter of the word(for example "five" <- e) is the first letter of the next word(for example e -> "eight")

For example one possible way to extend the list is after 18

> 9, 11, 9, so nine, eleven, nine

bonus:

> The smallest 4 positive numbers which cannot fit it are 4 (four), 5 (five), 6(six), 7(seven). No number ends with the letter "s" or "f", so it won't fit anywhere. Proof that others smaller than them can(i will write the 3 number after 18)
>  1 : ninety-two, one
>  2 : nine, eight, two
>  3 : nine, eight, three